# grouping table elements according to grouping column values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have [this table](http://derp.co.uk/4b9c6), with number of photon counts of an event in each energy channel.

The third column is the grouping of the channel: all the channel marked with `-1` are grouped into one single channel, whose origin is at the previous `1` grouping value. That is, in this example, all the channels from 0 to 39 are grouped into one single channel.

How can I create an array or list of counts with the grouping defined by the `group` column?
In this example, my resulting array would have two elements, one with the sum of the counts from the channel 0 to 39, and the other elements with the counts in the 40th channel.

I am sorry I am not able to give any starting code, but I don't really know how to start. Any suggestions really appreciated.

EDIT: the table is part of a FITS file. I read it by using `pyfits`:

```
import pyfits
data = pyfits.open('./file.fits')
chan    = data[1].data.field('channel')
counts    = data[1].data.field('counts')
groups    = data[1].data.field('grouping')
data.close()
```

`print type(chan)` returns `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`. The same for the other arrays.

Comment: how is that table represented on disk?  how would you read it in?

Comment: ahhhh, a fits file.  a fellow astronomer then?  hopefully learning Python to stop using IDL ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try,

```
chan = np.array( [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] )
counts = np.array( [0.,0.,5.,2.,0.,0.,1.,1.,1.,0.] )
groups = np.array( [1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1] )

indx = np.where( groups==1 )
# indx is a tuple with one entry for each dimension of the array groups
# in the next statement I just grab the first (and only) element of the tuple 
indx = indx[0]  

# next we split the array based on those indices
counts = np.split( counts, indx )
# counts is now a list of arrays 
# [array([], dtype=float64), array([ 0.,  0.,  5.,  0.,  0.]),array([ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.])]
# I use the if statement in the list comprehension to get rid of the first empty array

totals = np.array( [sum(c) for c in counts if len(c)>0] )
tchnls = np.split( chan, indx )[1:]
```

Then `totals` will be the sums of counts for each group,

```
>>> totals
array([ 7.,  3.])
```

and tchnls will be the channels that contributed to each group,

```
>>> tchnls
[array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot, I will try it as soon as possible. However, I thought a `list comprehensive` was possible, usually list comprehensive fix everything in python :)

Comment: oh, wait, I found a better way to do it with `np.split`, I'll update the answer

Comment: and now you get a list comprehension as well.  congrats!

Comment: Thanks again! But, the first element in the `totals` array should be `7.`, isn't it?

Comment: yes, you're right.  the code works, I just made a typo when entering the results of the print statement above.  updated the answer

Comment: Ok yes the code is great, thanks! I was sure the list was the right thing here ;) One last thing: how can I group the `channel` array too, in order to plot `(grouped)counts vs (grouped)channel`?

Comment: not sure what you mean here?  you want to plot the index of totals vs the values in totals?  For above would it be x = [0,1], y=[7.,3.]?  If so just `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.plot( totals )`

Comment: also, if this answer was helpful for your original question can you accept it by clicking the green arrow above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58467/discussion-between-py-ser-and-gabriel).

Comment: It is almost certainly faster to do `totals = np.add.reduceat(counts, idx)`.

Comment: Cool method.  I didn't know about it.